# Problema de rotas Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tendo um problema com um rota do meu sistema.

```
Route::get('/atualizacoes/list', 'AtualizacoesController@listarIndex')->name('atualizacoes.listar');
```

Pelo o que eu entendi ele está interpretando o "list" em "/atualizacoes/list" como se fosse um valor. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Erro:

> invalid input syntax for integer: \"list\" (SQL: select * from \"ger_atualizacao\" where \"att_codigo\" = list limit 1)"

Código do Controller:

```
public function show($id){
    $atualizacao = GerAtualizacao::where('att_codigo', $id)->first();

    return response()->json($atualizacao);
}

public function listarIndex(){
    $atualizacoes = GerAtualizacao::all();

    return response()->json($atualizacoes);
}
```

Era para ele entrar na função "listarIndex" mas ele entra na função "show"

Comment: Cara isso é problema de banco de dados... não da rota em sí, detalhe mais seu problema, poste o código do controller e se possível a descrição das tabelas envolvidas no controller.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código do controller

Comment: Por um acaso alguma das suas rotas tem o mesmo nome ou a mesma url?

Comment: Estou usando apiResource nas rotas, a não ser nessa rota que eu coloquei na pergunta

Comment: coloque o seguinte comando em algum lugar e nos mostre o resultado: `foreach (Route::getRoutes() as $route) {
    var_dump($route->getUri());
}`

Comment: Você provavelmente, definiu antes dessas rotas um `Route::resource`. No Laravel, se for usar resource com outras rotas, defina as rotas  sempre antes de declarar o `resource`.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Valeu, era esse mesmo o problema, porém agora a função "store" do resource parou de funcionar

Comment: @João.Mistura deixei respondido a sua pergunta, para ajudar outros usuários. Considere marcar a resposta como aceita, se achar que deve fazer isso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao meu ver, parece que você está usando `Route::resource` antes de definir a rota `atualizacoes.listar`.

Você precisa lembrar que, quando você usa `Route::resource`, ele vai criar uma rota que tem o segundo segmento¹ do `path` como um valor variável.

Exemplo:

```
 Route::resource('usuarios', 'UsuariosController');
```

Irá gerar:

```
GET  /usuarios
GET  /usuarios/{usuario} # preste atenção nessa
POST /usuarios
PUT  /usuarios/{usuario}
DELETE /usuarios/{usuario}
```

O que acontece é que, ao você definir a rota `"/atualizacoes/list"` depois de declarar o `resource`, o Laravel pesquisará as rotas declaradas primeiro, quando você fizer a requisição.

Ou seja `atualizacoes/{atualizacao}` tem prioridade sobre `/atualizacoes/list`. Isso faz com que `list` seja reconhecido como o parâmetro da sua rota `atualizacoes/{atualizacao}`, e não como segmento¹ de `atualizacoes/list`.

Recomendo no Laravel que, sempre que for usar `resource` e implementar outras rotas manualmente, declare o `Route::resource` do controller utilizado por último.

**Observações:**

¹ - As versões que usei do Laravel 3 e 4, chamava cada parte separada pela `/` de "segment", por isso usei a palavra "segmento". 
Por exemplo, `eu/sou/bonito` tem 3 seguimentos.

<sub>Eu assinalei isso nos comentários para o AP e ele confirmou que esse era o problema, respondi pra ficar documentado.</sub>

Comment: Entendi, mas tenho outra dúvida. No meu arquivo de rotas eu as organizei por item, por exemplo, as rodas de Atualizações coloquei juntas, as rotas de Usuário coloquei juntas tb. No caso eu preciso colocar as rotas Resource por ultimo independente do Controller que eu estou usando? Não sei se ficou claro minha dúvida.

Comment: @João.Mistura por último que eu falo é sempre depois da declaração manual. Exemplo: `Route::get('x/y', 'XController@y'); Route::resource('x', 'XController'); Route::get('quauqer_outra_rota');`

Comment: Entendi, valeu parceiro, me ajudou bastante